# mod rewrite, htaccess and gettign the values

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**the incoming URL**

> domain.com/12/3

**should be re-written to**

> domain.com/?w=12&h=3

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?w=$1&h=$2 [QSA]
```

**the php**

```
<?php
echo $_GET['h'];
?>
```

**Result**

> 404 page

I've tried using htaccess to change the result of the url and then retrieve the value from the URL, could someone help me out?

Comment: Do you get `$_GET['w']` normally?

Comment: using ?w=3&h=4   Yes it works

Comment: /index.php... as Chris explained below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?w=$1&h=$2 [QSA]
```

The above sorted it. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to escape `-` like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)$ index.php?w=$1&h=$2 [QSA]
```

PS. I hope the above URL /12/3 is just for example because your regex accepts only a-z

Comment: Escaping `-` makes no sense to me, but your PS is the correct answer. I can't  believe I missed that.

Comment: `-` is a regex character like `.*()[]&^` which need to be escaped whenever used literally!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?w=$1&h=$2 [QSA]
```

Essentially, I'm pretty sure you need a / in front of index.php

I like to use this generator for my mod-rewrite rules.

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: A `/` is not mandatory, though it makes the url more explicit I guess

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your rewriterule to the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?w=$1&h=$2 [QSA]
```

Your example has two digits as the first parts of the path, which won't be matched by `[a-z]`.